# Bind lookup column with another subsite list

Tags: lookup-column

I have a site "ABC Company" in which I have two subsites.

1. HR
2. Inventory

In HR subsite there is a list "Employee" which has a column "Full Name"

In Inventory subsite there is a list "Issue Inventory" which has a column of "Employee"

I want to bind lookup column in Inventory->Issue Inventory list with HR->Employee list.

Please advice how can I do this without using InfoPath. Its possible in InfoPath but InfoPath changes the look and feel of page thats why I want to do this either using sharePoint web environment or sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 3):

To create a cross-site lookup field do the following:

- Create the list that you want to be the source of your lookup field –
  must be deone at the site collection root.
- Create a new Site Column (at the site collection root as well ) which you define as a lookup field and the liste created above as
  your source
- Use the new site column field in your new list – anywhere in the site collection

[View here for detail.](http://bramnuyts.be/2011/04/11/creating-a-cross-site-lookup-field-without-code/)

There are many third party add-on which allows you to look up and pull information from any site in a site collection - See more at: http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint-cross-site-lookup